# using both layout-land and onConfigurationChanged()

Tags: android, rotation, onconfigurationchanged

I just want to change Layout when the device has been rotated. but I've found that onConfigurationChanged() must call onCreate() again using setContentView with separated
layout named of *_land.xml

```
if(getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().
getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, null);
else view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_land, null);
```

Project is too big and there are many codes to fix If onCreate again without finish().

I'd like somebody help this.

*Thank you.*

-> *onConfigurationChanged concept is keep layout I think*

Comment: What exactly you want ?? If you want to use both your activity will be restarted and data will be lost, you have two choices 1. save data using onSavedInstanceState or else fixes the orientation through manifest and dynamically create the view inside onConfigurationChanged() .. let me know i'll help you for the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*this is not no more interestes*

onConfigurationChanged() cannot be used with layout-land folder's machanism. That's because the callback concept is to keep Layout. So Activity which used the method should Inflate landscape Layout.

Answer (score 3):

Just call at the end of the method setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

So you can use the folder method as normal

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call the layout for landscape by your own, it will get called automatically if you follow the android folder structure.Like :

Suppose your layout name is "main.xml", then

Keep one main.xml file in layout folder and one in layout-land folder. so in the case of land scape mode, the system will automatically selects the layout from layout-land folder.

Check [this](http://www.how-to-develop-android-apps.com/how-to-make-a-landscape-layout-in-android/) link if you have any doubts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but It's not working properly. AndroidManifest has orientation|screenSize. what you said is working before using onConfigurationChanged method or deleting |screenSize.* Android API 14, ICS.

Answer (score 0):

You simply make a main.xml in layout-land folder (created by you not present by default) in res folder with same name as that of your main.xml in layout folder. But make  changes in linear layout tag, i.e. make it horizontal instad of vertical of main.xml which is situated in layout-land folder.

After all this you simply call `SetContentView(R.layout.main);`. And see the magic, your application will work. Also make changes in Android Manifest file, i.e. in your actvity tag make comment `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. below is what I've commented that. but this site is too popular to refresh. :-). -> but It's not working properly. AndroidManifest has orientation|screenSize. what you said is working before using onConfigurationChanged method or deleting |screenSize.* Android API 14, ICS.

Comment: That's make the screen disable to rotate i think. ** I've tested that onConfiguration is not support layout changing :( **